# Clojure: pre post functions

Tags: clojure

### Context

I'm aware of http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/

What I want is not exactly pre/post conditions.

I want to have pre/post *functions* that are executed *exactly* once.

I don't see any documentation promising me this feature about the pre/post conditions (i.e. that they're not executed multiple times.)

### Question

For a Clojure function, is there anyway to tag it with pre/post *functions* that are executed exactly once,

- the pre function when the function is called
- the post function when the function returns

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to only test once?

Comment: @ideally_world: I did not explain my question clearly. I want to have pre/post functions only executed once per function call; and I don't see anything about pre/post conditions that promises me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this relatively easily with a higher order function:

```
(defn wrap-fn [function pre post]
  (fn [& args]
    (apply pre args)
    (let [result (apply function args)]
      (apply post (cons result args)))))

(def f
  (wrap-fn
    +
    #(println (str "Calling function with args: " %&))
    #(println (str "Returning with result: " (first %&)))))

(f 2 3)
Calling function with args: (2 3)
Returning with result: 5
```

Comment: The followup is to do a (defmacro wrapped-defn ... ), which automatically takes care of this?

Comment: You could make it into a macro - but it doesn't *need* to be a macro so I would normally suggest keeping it as a function. Main benefit of making it a macro would be if you wanted to implement some specific custom syntax.

Comment: @mikera: Isn't the pre and post called every time you call `f` ? I guess the question is about to execute them only once i.e when the function is called first time ?

Comment: @Ankur: My question is not clear, I meant to say "exactly once per function call" -- the thing with pre/post conditions, is that I don't see any spec guaranteeing that they're not called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

[Dire](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire#preconditions) will do precisely this. All precondition predicates are invoked before the function is evaluated. If the predicates all return true, the function evaluates. Otherwise an exception is raised. Evaluation of all postcondition predicates follows.