# Clojure: Compile time insertion of pre/post functions

Tags: clojure

This is a followup to [Clojure: pre post functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778539/clojure-pre-post-functions)

### Goal

For every Clojure function, I want to have a *pre* and *post* function that gets executed:

- right before the function is evaluated and
- right after the function returns

  Now, I want to do this *all* functions in my *.clj files.

  I would prefer (this is also an learning exercise) to do this at the Clojure Compiler level.

### Question:

How do I get started on this? What part of the Clojure Compiler source code should I be reading? What documentation / tutorials on the internals of the Clojure Compiler I should be aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this sounds like a slightly crazy thing to do in general. There are almost certainly better ways to achieve any sensible objective (i.e. this is screaming "[XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)"). But as long as you say it is just for a learning exercise, that is fine :-)

I can think of a couple of strategies you might want to consider before hacking the compiler:

- Create your own `defn` macro that does the wrapping when functions are created. Obviously you'll need to make sure your own version of defn is used rather than the built-in one. Probably the simplest solution.
- Walk your namespaces at runtime (after they are loaded) and redefine all functions to a wrapped version of the same function. Could get a bit messy but will certainly enhance your understanding of namespaces :-)

If you really want to hack the compiler, the easiest place to make this change would probably be just by hacking `defn` in [core.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj)

Comment: I'd probably wrap `fn` in its own macro, since `defn` is just a convenience macro for defining functions and assigning them to symbols?

Comment: Yes you could wrap `fn`, but if so I think you'd need to redefine `defn` as well since it refers directly to `clojure.core/fn` rather than your own version....

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the insightful + helpful solutions (rather than the waves of "Why would you want to do this???" I was expecting :-).

Comment: @mikera: you should go answer my new question, so you can be 3/3 :-).